# How can I convert a relative image url to absolute image url in Vue js?

Tags: html, vue.js, src

I have a call to my API that gets me the relative path. I want to make it an absolute path by adding the domain name. How can I do this in Vue js?

```
<img :src="`https://my_domain.com` {{ item.settings.image.path }}>
```

The `item.settings.image.path` is the call to my API and returns something like `/storage/uploads/my_picture.jpg`.

I can't find any resources online and I am not sure about the syntax. I get a parsing error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:12) at Parser.pp$4.raise`

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean with call to your API? What value does `item.settings.image.path` returning?

Comment: `item` is an object, can you also include what error do you get ?

Comment: @SiliconMachine updated, please check.

Comment: @SatyamPathak `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:12) at Parser.pp$4.raise`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your syntax is wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), should be:

```
<img :src="`https://my_domain.com${item.settings.image.path}`">
```

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    link: '/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg',
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img :src="`https://i.ytimg.com${link}`">
</div>
```